# How to return a description with the form_error event in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the form_error event in MS Access to catch errors, which gives only a `dataerr integer` and not a description like a vba error, however the [MS Website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836345.aspx) gives the following description of the event:

> You can use the DataErr argument with the Error function to map the
>   number to the corresponding error message

But doesn't actually give an example of this and I'm struggling to figure it out.

The specific situation is that the user will be updating records in a subform, some fields may break referential integrity rules, the number will only tell me that a referential integrity rule has been broken, whereas the description will give me the table name, which allows me to give a prescriptive error message relating to the field where the error occurs

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can try the `DBEngine.Errors` collection (this is a different thing than the `VBA.Err` object), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835711.aspx . It is useful to get more information about ODBC errors, I'm not sure it will help in your case.

Comment: I've tried triggering this in various places but the collection is always empty, the collection seems to relate more to attempting to open an external database than working within one

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate function to perform all of your validation and message the user with anything missing. Run that in the form's beforeupdate event and cancel the event if needed. That would probably eliminate many of your form_error's. In the form_error event, you could call the same function. It is has found an issue, suppress the default message. Any other error that pops up you'll can handle separately if needed.

Comment: This is fine for missing data etc. I am specifically referring to referential integrity though. In order to check for that I'd believe I'd have to go down the DLookup route, which just seem's like a lot of effort to circumvent access inbuilt table relationships functionality.

Comment: I agree that it's not ideal, however, AFAIK what you (and all of us) would like, doesn't exist. Lookups should be minimal if you are using comboboxes and/or listboxes for data entry.

Comment: I think the previous comment would be my answer too. If user input can break ref. integrity, don't allow arbitrary input, let the user select from a combobox. @HelloWorld

Comment: In this case I want the user to be able to retrieve and work with multiple records directly, which is why I'm specifically looking at error and change events rather than linking to buttons/comboboxes with a standard on error goto with an update/insert etc. I agree that using before update event on field/form seems to be the best **workaround**, I'll upvote as such, but leave as unanswered in case someone has a direct solution

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is just to pass the number to *Error* to obtain the description:

```
MsgBox Error(DataErr)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just returns application-defined or object-defined error in the msgbox

Comment: Did you run it in the sub function itself? Anyway, I believe the common errors are these: [DataErr 2169 Customization]http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1080271

Comment: Yes it's running in the sub function. The link you provide goes along the same lines as AVG suggestion above of using the before update event rather than the on error event, although again is not referring to referential integrity checks, rather error situations where the number is sufficient. It seems frustrating that this is the solution. The error description I need in my code is right there on the default message, but there seems to be no way to work with it

Answer (score 1):

### In short

As far as I know @AVG's solution is probably the best available workaround, with one exception. That is, @AVG probably gets it right that the best workaround is to: try to catch the error at the `Form_BeforeUpdate` event; and (probably, depending on your needs) cancel the event in `Form_BeforeUpdate`.

However, it is a good idea *not to* suppress the default error at the `Form_Error` level. If you catch and cancel the error at `Form_BeforeUpdate` then the error won't arise at `Form_Error`. So there's no need to suppress the error at `Form_Error` in that case. But if there's another kind of referential integrity violation laying in wait (e.g. an Category/Organisation violation rather than a Category/Subcategory violation), that you haven't thought to handle as a developer, then having the default error message arise in `Form_Error` will alert you to it. You wouldn't want to suppress a message for an error you haven't caught.

Below I provide example code for this workaround.

I also discuss how `AccessError(DataErr)` looks like a possible solution, but isn't quite. That is, it can be used to map `DataErr` numbers to messages. This is partially helpful. But, unfortunately, the messages are the variable *unsubstituted* versions. So, for example, we can't use `AccessError(DataErr)` in code to interrogate *specific* referential integrity violation messages.

### Making the problem sharper

A `Form_Error` event will fire when a user, through a form: violates referential integrity (that you've set precisely to prevent such attempts at invalid data states); violates a validation rule set at the table level; or otherwise (?) produces a data error.

However, the default message returned is likely to be user-unfriendly. E.g., in the case of a referential integrity violation ...

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'CategorySubcategory'.

In this example the table 'CategorySubcategory' expresses a many-to-many relationship between tables 'Category' and 'CategorySubcategory', defining the particular Subcategories that belong to particular Categories. (In my example) it is also expressed, in CategorySubcategory, that some of the Categories have no Subcategories.

What's needed is a means to have a user friendly message in place of the user-unfriendly message. And to do this it would be convenient to interrogate the default error message as it arises, suppress it, and substitute your own.

(As far as I know) the closest we can come to interrogating the default message, in `Form_Error`, is `AccessError(DataErr)`. Unlike `Error(DataErr)`, `AccessError` promises to

[Microsoft > Docs > Office VBA Reference > Access > Object model > Application object > Methods > AccessError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.accesserror)

> ... return the descriptive string associated with a Microsoft Access or **DAO error** [Emphasis added]
>
> [And the promise is that you] can use the AccessError method to return a descriptive string from within a form's Error event.

So you might be tempted to do something like, and it would be convenient if you could do something like ...

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

  If AccessError(DataErr) Like "*CategorySubcategory*" Then
    MsgBox "[My user friendly message] Choose the right Subcategory given the Category; or change the Category.", vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation
    Response = acDataErrContinue ' Suppress default message
  End If

End Sub
```

### Might `AccessError` work?

However, it turns out `AccessError` only returns the variable *unsubstituted* version of the error message, not the variable *substituted* message the user sees at run-time. For example `AccessError` returns something like ...

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table '|'.

... rather than ...

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'CategorySubcategory'.

To prove this trigger a *data* error (E.g. by violating referential integrity) with the following.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

  ' For some reason you'll need to call AccessError(DataErr) before Error(DataErr) 
  Debug.Print "AccessError(DataErr): ", AccessError(DataErr)
  Debug.Print "Error(DataErr): ", Error(DataErr)

End Sub
```

Observe both: `AccessError` returns a specific message where `Error` returns the uselessly generic 'Application-defined or object-defined error'; and `AccessError` returns the variable *unsubstituted* version of the error message.

@Hello World correctly quotes from [MS Docs > ... > Form.Error event (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Access.Form.Error)

> You can use the DataErr argument with the Error function to map the number to the corresponding error message

Even with `AccessError` substituted for `Error` @Hello World's lament remains fair ...

> [The MS docs don't] actually give an example of this and I'm struggling to figure it out.

### Mapping messages to the `DataErr` number

What the MS doc author probably has in mind is code like the following

```
Function AccessAndJetErrorsTable() As Boolean
' Source: Access 2000 Help "Determine the Error Codes Reserved by Microsoft Access
'          and the Microsoft Jet Database Engine"
    Const strTable As String = "zttblAccessAndJetErrors"
    Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
    Dim tbl As New ADOX.Table
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset, lngCode As Long
    Dim strAccessErr As String
    
    Const conAppObjectError = "Application-defined or object-defined error"
    On Error GoTo Error_AccessAndJetErrorsTable

    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
        ' Create Errors table with ErrorNumber and ErrorDescription fields.
    tbl.Name = strTable
    tbl.Columns.Append "ErrorCode", adInteger
    tbl.Columns.Append "ErrorString", adLongVarWChar
    
    Set cat.ActiveConnection = cnn
    cat.Tables.Append tbl
    ' Open recordset on Errors table.
    rst.Open strTable, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    ' Loop through error codes.
    For lngCode = 0 To 35000
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Raise each error.
        strAccessErr = AccessError(lngCode)
        DoCmd.Hourglass True
        ' Skip error numbers without associated strings.
        If strAccessErr <> "" Then
            ' Skip codes that generate application or object-defined errors.
            If strAccessErr <> conAppObjectError Then
                ' Add each error code and string to Errors table.
                rst.AddNew
                rst!ErrorCode = lngCode
                ' Append string to memo field.
                rst!ErrorString = strAccessErr
                rst.Update
            End If
        End If
    Next lngCode
    ' Close recordset.
    rst.Close
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    RefreshDatabaseWindow
    MsgBox strTable & " errors table created."
    AccessAndJetErrorsTable = True

Exit_AccessAndJetErrorsTable:
    Exit Function

Error_AccessAndJetErrorsTable:
    MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
    AccessAndJetErrorsTable = False
    Resume Exit_AccessAndJetErrorsTable
End Function
```

To use that code, create a new Database, put the code in a module, your cursor in the middle of the code, then hit F5 (to run it). A table `zttblAccessAndJetErrors` will be created where you can look up all the variable *unsubstituted* versions of the Access and Jet error messages; and correspond these to a `DataErr` number.

That code will give you the most up to date list of error messages. However, as an alternative you could just lookup an online source where this is published. E.g. [FMS > Microsoft Access 2010 Error Numbers and Descriptions](https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Errors/ErrorNumber_Description2010.html)

So either with `zttblAccessAndJetErrors` or a lookup online you can now determine the `DataErr` number that corresponds most closely to the error message you are seeing during testing. So that gives us the ability to do something like ...

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

  Select Case DataErr
    Case 3201
      ' "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table '|'."
      
        MsgBox "[My user friendly message] Choose the right Subcategory given the Category; or change the Category.", vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation
        Response = acDataErrContinue ' Suppress default message

  End Select
End Sub
```

That is, we don't use `AccessError` directly in `Form_Error` to return a message. Rather we've used `AccessError` (or relied on someone else to have used) to produce the DataErr/Message mapping. In `Form_Error` we continue to match against the `DataErr` number only. But now we can copy the relevant message as a comment for our `DataErr` number.

However, at least in this referential integrity (DataErr 3201) case our problem remains. If we suppressed the default message for a specific referential integrity violation (like a Category/Subcategory mismatch), as with the code above, then that risks burying other specific referential integrity violations. E.g. If another referential integrity violation occurred with respect to, say a Category and Organisation chosen by the user, then the above code would wrongly express (beguilingly in a user friendly manner) that a Category/Subcategory violation had occurred.

### The probable best available workaround

So, as far as I know @AVG's solution is probably the best available workaround, with one exception. That is, @AVG probably gets it right that the best workaround is to: try to catch the error at the `Form_BeforeUpdate` event; and (probably, depending on your needs) cancel the event in `Form_BeforeUpdate`.

However, it is a good idea *not to* suppress the default error at the `Form_Error` level. If you catch and cancel the error at `Form_BeforeUpdate` then the error won't arise at `Form_Error`. So there's no need to suppress the error at `Form_Error` in that case. But if there's another kind of referential integrity violation laying in wait (e.g. an Category/Organisation violation rather than a Category/Subcategory violation), that you haven't thought to handle as a developer, then having the default error message arise in `Form_Error` will alert you to it. You wouldn't want to suppress a message for an error you haven't caught.

So, in my case, the workaround code looks like (having to "go down the DLookup route" as @Hello World suggests).

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

  ' Head off a Form_Error referential integrity error 3201:
  ' "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'CategorySubcategory'."
  Dim subCategoryIDGivenCategoryIDAtTableLevel As Variant
  If IsNull(Me.cboSubcategory) Then
    subCategoryIDGivenCategoryIDAtTableLevel = DLookup("[SubcategoryID]", "[CategorySubcategory]", "[CategoryID] = " & Me.cboCategory)

    If Not IsNull(subCategoryIDGivenCategoryIDAtTableLevel) Then
      ' The user has not chosen a value for cboSubcategory, when they should have chosen some value
      message = "For this Category you need to choose a Subcategory. Either choose a Subcategory or change the Category."
      Me.cboSubcategory.SetFocus
      Cancel = True
    End If

  End If

  If Cancel Then
    MsgBox message, vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, GetApplicationTitle() & " (Record Level Validation)"
  End If

End if

Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  Select Case DataErr
    Case 3201
      ' A referential integrity error ...
      ' "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table '|'."
      
      ' We display the default error message in case we haven't caught a referential integrity
      ' condition in Form_BeforeUpdate
      Response = acDataErrDisplay

  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: From [@Grunty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6269214/grunty): _In the BeforeUpdate handler, the_ Not _seems to be misplaced. Shouldn't it read: `If *Not* IsNull(Me.cboSubcategory)` and `If IsNull(subCategoryIDGivenCategoryIDAtTableLevel)`?_

Answer (score 0):

I always use the below code pattern so that users can get a proper error message, which they can then convey to me to understand the reason.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
On Error GoTo Sub_Err

     --Your code here---

'errors catching stuff
Sub_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Sub_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Sub_Exit
End Sub
```

Use the same thing for every `sub` you use in code.

Comment: This doesn't relate to the form_error event, there is no button clicked and error$ returns nothing in the case of this question, that's exactly the problem